# Atomic statement ignored without volatile keyword

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, atomic, volatile

The java concurrency tutorial states that:

> Reads and writes are atomic for reference variables and for most primitive variables (all types except long and double).
>   Reads and writes are atomic for all variables declared volatile (including long and double variables).

I created a simple experiment to test this

```
package experiment0;

public class Experiment0 {

    public static int i=9;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        i=9;
        (new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                while(i==9){
                    //System.out.println("i==9");
                }
                System.out.println("\ni!=9");
            }
        }).start();
        (new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                    i=8;
                }catch(Exception e){

                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

When I run this code the program never gets terminated! In order for it to work I either have to uncomment the line inside the while loop of the first thread or declare `i` as `volatile`.
Am I missing something? Is the documentation wrong and should it say that all primitives should be declared as volatiles in these kind of cases? Why does a write to `System.out` "solve" the problem? Does it give enough time to the second thread to change `i`?

Comment: well works fine for both in my case..

Comment: The part of the manual that you quote and the problem that your code has are not really related. "Atomic" writes does not mean that another thread will see those changes. One thing you could do to explore that in more detail is to see if the compiler optimizes the reads and that's why you don't see the updates.

Comment: Atomic means the update is indivisible. You never see an in-between state, only the old or new value. If you only see the old value it is still atomic.

Comment: For an explanation of why writing to System.out solves the problem, see [Loop doesn't see changed value without a print statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25425130/loop-doesnt-see-changed-value-without-a-print-statement).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A write being atomic means that the write is executed as a single, atomic operation. No other thread could see something other than the value before the assignment, or after the assignment.

For example, in the case of long values, an assignment is not atomic because it's actualy executed as two operations: one which assigns the first 32 bits, and one which assigns the last 32 bits. So another thread might read the variable's value after only one of the two operations has been executed, ans thus see a value that is neither the before nor the after value, but an "in-between" value.

What your program demonstrates is that writing to a variable without any kind of synchronization causes **visibility** problems between threads. The write done by one thread is not visible by another thread. This is due to processors each having their own cache, and not writing to the main memory at each assignment. To make sure a write is visible, you need to make the variable volatile, or to synchronize access to the variable, or to use an AtomicInteger.

Comment: Oh I get it thanks! I had never heard of the visibility concept before.

Comment: @JB Nizet: Wouldn't modern processors have Cache coherency implemented in hardware? So when 'i=8' is executed in one processor, and then read by another processor, the hardware would flush the cache and read it from memory.?

Comment: @vikky.rk Yes. However, the Java memory model does not require the architecture to be cache-coherent, and the Java virtual machine is allowed to optimize the loop `while (i==9) { }` into `if (i == 9) { while (true) { } }`. Due to such optimizations, you can still experience thread visibility problems on cache-coherent architectures.